# Python Pillow ImageChops.difference always None

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to compare screenshots of 2 interactive maps. The screenshots are taken with Selenium and using Pillow to compare.

```
...
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import ImageChops, Image

...

png_bytes1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body").screenshot_as_png
png_bytes2 = driver2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body").screenshot_as_png

img1 = Image.open(BytesIO(png_bytes1))
img2 = Image.open(BytesIO(png_bytes2))

diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)
print(diff.getbbox())
```

But diff is always blank. I manually used img1.show() and img2.show() to obtain the images below. diff.show() is always blank and diff.getbbox() prints None. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way of doing it?

**Update: It works if I first save these images as jpg. Anyone have ideas why?**

[image: google maps with menu]
[image: google maps with no menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `ImageChops.difference()` will only work if the image parameters are Image objects. PNG files are PngImageFile objects, with an RGBA mode for an extra alpha layer and need to be [converted](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) using `converted_img1 = img1.convert('RGB')`.